# get the image url with vuejs2 and paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vuejs2, paperclip

I'm working with paper clip, rails and vue. My problem is how I get the url of the image with vuejs2

app.js

```
var posts = #{ sanitize @posts.to_json }
    var app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        posts: posts
      }
    })
```

app.haml

```
#app
  %div{ 'v-for' => 'post in posts' }
    %img{ ':src' => 'post.avatar' }
```

post

```
{ "id": 7, "title": "first post", "description": "lorem", "avatar_file_name": "batman.jpg", "avatar_content_type": "image/jpeg", "avatar_file_size": 32823, "avatar_updated_at": "2018-04-23T04:19:06.527Z" }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to write a new `.as_json` function or monkeypatch that one for your `Post` class to read something like:

```
def as_vue_json
  { id: id, 
    title: title, 
    avatar_url: avatar.url(:original),
    description: description }
end
```